# Resizing Ubuntu Server partitions in a Xen environment

Tags: ubuntu, xen

I need to increase an Ubuntu partition, in a Xen environment.
Through XenCenter, I increased the disk, from 10GB to 100 GB.
Now I can see "xvda" size 100 GB.
For reasons I don't know, in xvda, I have: xvda1, xvda2, xvda5
The root (/) is in xvda5, together with a swap.
Follows my fdisk command:

```
Disk /dev/xvda: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x69465e7c

Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/xvda1 *       2048   999423   997376  487M 83 Linux
/dev/xvda2      1001470 20969471 19968002  9.5G  5 Extended
/dev/xvda5      1001472 20969471 19968000  9.5G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/xvdd: 1.8 TiB, 1988569858048 bytes, 3883925504 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/xvdb: 1.8 TiB, 1988569858048 bytes, 3883925504 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntuservermain--vg-root: 8.5 GiB, 9126805504 bytes, 17825792 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntuservermain--vg-swap_1: 1020 MiB, 1069547520 bytes, 2088960 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

What are the commands I need? I tried solutions taken on the web and stack exchange, without luck.
There is a command I found **growpart** that seems perfect for my needs, but it doesn't seem to work.

As requested, I add the results of another command, **lsblk**:

```
NAME                            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0                              11:0    1 67.8M  0 rom
xvda                            202:0    0  100G  0 disk
├─xvda1                         202:1    0  487M  0 part /boot
├─xvda2                         202:2    0    1K  0 part
└─xvda5                         202:5    0  9.5G  0 part
  ├─ubuntuservermain--vg-root   252:0    0  8.5G  0 lvm  /
  └─ubuntuservermain--vg-swap_1 252:1    0 1020M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
xvdb                            202:16   0  1.8T  0 disk
xvdd                            202:48   0  1.8T  0 disk
```

Comment: Could you please add to your question the output of: `lsblk` ?

Comment: done. thank you very much!

Comment: Thank for your script, anyway I didn't want to mess up with all the command line, as I expected it to be much easier than it was. So I loaded up a a live Ubuntu, and with gparted I easily increased the partition. Gparted correctly visualized the xvda5 partition nested into the xvda2, I don't know the reason for the command line visualized in that way, so probably I should have deleted the xvda2 with fdisk, then create it (increased); gparted did that in a matter of seconds! then I had to resize the LVM partition (/dev/mapper/partition) using lvextend. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Sorry, I had to use resize2fs in addition to lvextend to increase the filesystem...

Comment: xvda5 is a logical partition located inside the extended partition xvda2. Do not delete  xvda2 See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#Disk_partitioning and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_boot_record

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [script](https://github.com/mircea-vutcovici/scripts/blob/master/vol_resize.sh) that I am using to show the commands to resize volumes.

In your case you will need to:

1. Use fdisk and delete extended partition xvda5 and recreate it with the same start sector and leave the default (last sector on current the resized disk).
2. Then you need to expand the LVM disk label with `pvresize`.
3. Then the logical volume with `lvresize --resizefs --size +1G` (to add 1GB to root volume).

The script will generated the proper commands for your environment. The resize is possible to be done online, without stopping any application or unmounting any file system.

Download the script and run it:

```
bash vol_resize.sh --block-device /dev/mapper/ubuntuservermain--vg-root
```

Add the output to the question and I can explain the generated output.